# с - warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type

Tags: linux, c, gcc, terminal, clang

Есть код, [позаимствованный из общественного источника](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806671/7104681). Задача этой функции - дождаться нажатия **любой** клавиши в терминале Linux и продолжить выполнение. Функция работает замечательно, но при сборке gcc выдаёт предупреждение:

```
warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]
  ttynew.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO); /* disable canonical mode */
```

И даже clang выдаёт свой warning:

```
warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
        ttynew.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
                   ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Анализ источников проблемы не прояснил ситуации:

termbits.h:

```
struct termios {
    ...
    tcflag_t c_lflag;    /* local mode flags */
    ...
};

typedef unsigned int tcflag_t;

#define ICANON 0000002
#define ECHO 0000010
```

И на старых gcc, и на новых ситуация идентична. Это баг в стандартных библиотеках или ЧЯДНТ?

```
/**
 * @brief Wait for a while when any key will be pressed
 */
char press_any_key(void){

    // Return result
    char ch = 0;

    // save old terminal attributes
    struct termios ttyold,ttynew;
    /* get current terminal attirbutes; 0 is the file descriptor for stdin */
    if (tcgetattr(0, &ttynew) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting terminal attributes\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ttyold = ttynew;

    ttynew.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO); /* disable line buffering and feedback */
     /* set immediately */
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &ttynew);

    // Press any key there
    if (scanf("%c",&ch) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf() error\n");
    }

    // Return old settings
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &ttyold) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting terminal attributes\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return(ch);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Правильный код после правок. Спасибо @AnT и @sanmai!

```
/**
 * @brief Wait for a while when any key will be pressed
 * @details When you read from stdin (with getchar(), or
 * any other way), it will return characters immediately,
 * without waiting for a Return/Enter. In addition, backspace
 * will no longer 'work' -- instead of erasing the last character,
 * you'll read an actual backspace character in the input.
 * Also, you'll want to make sure to restore canonical mode before your
 * program exits, or the non-canonical handling may cause odd effects
 * with your shell.
 *
 */
char press_any_key(void){

    // Return result
    char ch = 0;

    // save old terminal attributes
    struct termios ttyold,ttynew;
    /* get current terminal attirbutes; 0 is the file descriptor for stdin */
    if (tcgetattr(0, &ttynew) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting terminal attributes\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ttyold = ttynew;

    // Cast to tcflag_t because there is the error without it:
    // warning: negative integer implicitly converted to unsigned type [-Wsign-conversion]
    // .c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO); /* disable canonical mode */
    // warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-conversion]
    // .c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    //      ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ttynew.c_lflag &= ~((tcflag_t) ICANON | (tcflag_t) ECHO); /* disable line buffering and feedback */
     /* set immediately */
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &ttynew);

    // Press any key there
    if (scanf("%c",&ch) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf() error\n");
    }

    // Return old settings
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &ttyold) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed getting terminal attributes\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return(ch);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, тогда какое решение можно считать изящным? Отключать предупреждения для всего кода не вариант.

Comment: Если вы хотите привести типы, то делайте это явно. Тогда ворнинг должен уйти: `(unsigned int) ~(ICANON | ECHO)`

Comment: Да, так изящнее всего. Спасибо @sanmai. Поправил.

Comment: Опубликованное решение - скорее не "правильный подход", а просто подавление предупреждения через явное приведение типов. "Правильным подходом" скорее было бы выполненение приведения еще *до* того, как начали выполнятся битовые операции, причем возможно приведение лучше делать именно к `tcflag_t`: `ttynew.c_lflag &= ~((tcflag_t) ICANON | (tcflag_t) ECHO)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это и баг, и фича.

- Фича - потому что язык C делает такую конверсию за вас. Потому такие предупреждения не показываются по умолчанию.
- Баг - потому что разработчики библиотеки не подумали [явно указать что их константы - без знака](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310456/is-the-integer-constants-default-type-signed-or-unsigned). Значит, компилятору приходится приводить типы.

Короче, с этим предупреждением по-хорошему вы должны ничего делать кроме как отключить показ таких предупреждений вообще.

Но если вы хотите любой ценой его убрать, то это можно сделать явным приведением типа:

```
ttynew.c_lflag &= (unsigned int) ~(ICANON | ECHO);
```

Предупреждение при компиляции пропадёт.

Comment: Спасибо, @sanmai

Comment: AnT подкинул идею как решить проблему без отключения предупреждений, что важно. Идея уже реализована. Готовый код опубликовал в теле вопроса. Вас в любом случае благодарю за уделённое время на ответ. Плюсую в карму )

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор не выдает сообщение об ошибке. Компилятор выдает *предупреждение*. В данном случае это то предупреждение, которое и на самом деле является просто *предупреждением*, а не "ошибкой, которую gcc решил не считать ошибкой". То есть код формально корректен с точки зрения языка С.

Константы `ICANON` и `ECHO` - восьмеричные константы типа `int`. Результат операции `ICANON | ECHO` имеет тип `int` и положительное значение. Результат применения `~` к `ICANON | ECHO` имеет тип `int` и *отрицательное* значение.

Затем это отрицательное значение участвует в операции `&=` с операндом типа `unsigned int`. В такой ситуации по правилам языка С "побеждает" беззнаковый тип, т.е. вышеупомянутое значение типа `int` будет неявно преобразовано к типу `unsigned int`. Таким образом у вас имеет место неявное преобразование отрицательного значения к типу `unsigned int`. Об этом вас и предупреждает компилятор, на всякий случай. Формальной ошибки в таком неявном преобразовании нет - оно разрешено и четко определено правилами языка.

В данном случае на платформе с *дополнительным кодом* ничего страшного не произойдет и все будет работать "как надо", ибо преобразование `int` -> `unsigned int` на такой платформе чисто концептуально и битового представления числа не меняет.

Но во избежание предупреждения не мешало бы избавиться от знаковых типов в битовых операциях и везде использовать беззнаковые типы

```
#define ICANON 0000002u
#define ECHO 0000010u
```

Comment: Благодарю за детальный ответ! Поправил код, добавил переопределеление макросов и всё собирается без предупреждений. Работает like a charm. Что и требовалось. Исправленный вариант сейчас опубликую в теле вопроса. Спасибо @AnT )

Comment: **> Константы ICANON и ECHO - восьмеричные константы типа int** @AnT, если не затруднит, разъясните, пожалуйста, новичку, как можно понять что это именно int, но не char, например. Я вижу только маску на семь бит.

Comment: @Dennis V.R.: Правила выбора типа бессуффиксных восьмеричных констант оговорены стандартом С: выбирается первый подходящий тип из последовательности `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`. Целочисленные константы в С никогда не имеют типа, меньшего чем `int`.

Comment: Понял. Теперь припоминаю. Спасибо ещё раз! )

Answer (score 1):

Из опубликованных тут решений, оба решения имеют проблемы:

1. В случае изменения библиотеки, вам придется поддерживать ее самому до скончания веков. В данном случае termbits.h:
2. В случае, если просто "прикастить" нужный тип, то это убирает варнинг только для текущей реализации. В будущем тип может измениться и варнинг вернется (хотя на практике этого навернка не будет).

Comment: Поменяться на какой должен тип чтобы ворнинг вернулся?

Comment: На любой другой. Это не будет ошибкой, просто снова всплывет варнинг.

Comment: Выбираю кастовать, хотя бы потому, что можно увидеть сообщение об ошибке. В случае с #undef сообщение во время сборки можно и не увидеть, но получить проблему в случае изменений библиотеки или сборке на другой платформе.